# Issue While Creating Build in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am running a command **ng build -prod -aot false** in terminal . Instead of creating a build it opens a new editor.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ng build -prod --no-aot` instead

Comment: Still it opens editor . I have tried different Commands but it only opens editor